# Reading from a file and writing it back to a file in java(Having trouble understanding BufferedWriter write method in java)

Tags: java, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I'm confused with the the java BufferedWriter write method. The java documents says that write takes int as an argument.

void   write(int c)    Writes a single character.

But I have used write method in my code, and I have passed String into it

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(file);
BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(file1);
String line=null;
while((line=br.readLine())!=null) 
{
  bw.write(line); // Why is this statement working?
  bw.write("\r\n");
}

I passing "line" to bw.write(line) and "line" is a string, why is this working?Is write 
method  overloaded?But I don't see it in docs.
```

Comment: [Here is the documentation for BufferedWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html). See also the methods in the _Writer_ parent type.

Comment: Thank you sir. I realize my question was dumb, actually I'm a beginner. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there's a `write()` that accept an String, and `BufferedWriter` "IS-A" Writer subclass, so that's why it has a `write(String)`, because `Writer` class has it.

Comment: Thank you sir. I realize my question was dumb, actually I'm a beginner. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hey, i'm not that old lol, Don't worry, always look for the subclasses in the API to see if there's more method you can find useful. Accept as best answer if i helped you with the problem :-)

Comment: Yeah, well almost all my uncles are programmer that's why

Answer (score 0):

Api copy / paste : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html

Class BufferedWriter

java.lang.Object
    java.io.Writer <------ *has method write(String str)
      java.io.BufferedWriter

There is a write method which is capable to take a string as param and write it.

As Luis Alberto allready mentioned.

Comment: Thank you sir. I realize my question was dumb, actually I'm a beginner. Thanks a lot.